fstab not mounting but manual mount works
How can I mount via fstab?
# /etc/fstab
//fritz.box/FRITZ.NAS /media/fritz cifs username=foo,password=bar,vers=1.0 0 0

followed by sudo mount -a; ls /media/fritz/ leads to nothing
While this one works swimmingly:
sudo mount -t cifs //fritz.box/FRITZ.NAS/ /media/fritz -o user=foo,pass=bar -o vers=1.0


Linux (by default) will try to mount filesystems before it starts up the network services. If the filesystem is on the otherside of the network, the mount will fail. Add the _netdev option in fstab.
This should be documented in the mount man page on your host.
